# How can I download an image based on a url in PHP? curl?

Tags: php, html

I have used a input file code to upload image to my wallpaper site..

```
    <input type="file" name="img" id="img" />
```

Is there anyway to select a image without selecting image file..like entering URL to text box?

```
    <input name="img" type="text" id="img" value="http://www.somesite.com/image.my.jpg" size="40" />
```

I tried its not working...please help me! Anyway to enter image url to text box  except select browse button and selecting image file? help me i tries in different ways...
Is there anyway to user type="text" excepts type="file" so We can enter image url in that text box and upload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that `<input>` you then have to tell your PHP code to go and download that file e.g.

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['img'])) {
  file_put_contents('savedImage',file_get_contents($_POST['img']));
}
```

However doing so opens you up to some potential security issues, so be careful!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is upload an image and then display that on a page.

You need to move the image into  a folder on your webserver then display that output.
[More info about it here.](http://webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=101466)